# Side-by-side diff of edits stretches outside screen

Tags: bug, edits, user-interface, diff

I'm using Chrome (88.0.4324.104) with page scale set to 150%, and a maximized Chrome window.

Recently (maybe a week or two ago) I noticed that side-by-side edits comparison doesn't fit the screen:

[image: doesn't fit]

"Before" part is fully visible, "After" is not, there is scroll. They used to be both visible.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, I'm not sure it is the same. I don't remember any page-wide scrolbars. Their appearance *is a problem*. Scrollbar in code-blocks is probably related

Comment: It's the same bug.